# Can i serve multiple ghost blog service without NGINX?

Tags: node.js, express, unix-socket

I'm using a web hosting service and I don't have permission to install NGINX, only listening on port 8080. so, I am looking for a way to use Unix Socket using Express. How can I solve this problem?

the next is my express router source

```
const express = require('express');
var PORT= process.env.PORT || 8080;

app.use("/tech", 
    function (req, res) {
        let to = `https://localhost:6869`; // Tech blog but nobody can connect to 6869
        res.redirect(to); 
    }
);
app.use("/",
    function (req, res) {
        let to = `https://localhost:6868`; // Main blog but nobody can connect to 6868
        res.redirect(to); 
    }
);

//listen
app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log('Example app listening on port', PORT);
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) { 
    console.log(err);
});
```

What is different way from the above?

(eg. "res.redirect()" -------> "server.listen('/tmp/sock', function() {,,,,,}")

help me please!